# Power BI CAGR% in a Table Visual

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a measure to calculate the CAGR% for last 3 yrs which is working perfectly fine in a Card Visual, but the moment I get the measure in a table visual my entire table throws an error 'Can't display the visual'.

Any help would highly be appreciated.

```
CAGR% =  CALCULATE(([CY_Sales]/[PY_-2_Sales])^(1/3)-1)
```

Comment: # Provide the Error message here. # Show some sample data if possible for better understanding. # provide code for [CY_Sales] and [PY_-2_Sales]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use **Divide()** instead of **"/"** - it is better performance wise and you do not have to handle the "divison by 0" error
2. The table visual would show you just one value - the measure. But if you have another colum, then the measure is calculated for every row (and with the context of the data in other columns). And probably you get a division/0 for a specific row. So: use DIVIDE() and probably this will already solve our problem.